# My auto test fails because it could not focus on a popup window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My auto test fails because it cannot focus on a popup window. WindowHandles gets 2 windows and it should focus on a popup window with a title called 'Task', but it focuses on the wrong one.

MAIN TEST:

```
new Case(Context)
                .ShouldGoToNewCaseUrlConnectedToIndividual()
                .ShouldChooseTypeInDropDown("No Show")
                .ShouldTypeInDueDate()
                .ShouldClickSave()
                .ShouldClickNewTask();

            new Task(Context)
                **.ShouldFocusTaskWindow();**


public Task ShouldFocusTaskWindow()
        {
            **FocusWindowOrPopup**(windowTitle);
            WaitUntilVisible(By.Id("Content_ctrlTaskControl_lblCaseNumber"));
            return this;
        }

    protected bool FocusWindowOrPopup(string windowTitle)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var window in Context.WebDriver.WindowHandles)
                {
                    Context.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(window);
                    string titl = Context.WebDriver.Title;
                    if (Context.WebDriver.Title.Equals(windowTitle))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }                                 
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //return false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        throw new Exception($"Could not focus window: {windowTitle}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the window title use the window handle

```
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
FocusWindowOrPopup(currentHandle);

protected bool FocusWindowOrPopup(string currentHandle)
    for (string winHandle in driver.WindowHandles) {
        if (!winHandle.Equals(currentHandle))
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. Let me try to implement your code, i'll get back if it worked or not.

Comment: Hello Guy! I implemented your code and i't still could not focus on the current popup window. My first code befor the focus window is as follows:private void CreateWindowTitle()
  {
   windowTitle = "Task";
  }

  public Task ShouldFocusTaskWindow()
  {
            var popup = GetBrowserName();
            FocusWindowOrPopup(windowTitle);
   WaitUntilVisible(By.Id("Content_ctrlTaskControl_lblCaseNumber"));
   return this;
  }

Comment: @DanA Why do you think it didn't work? you can't find an element? post how you are trying to locate it and the html.

Comment: Yes, it can't find the element because it's focusing on the wrong window, and that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually iterate through all available window handles and check for a matching window title.

See sample implementation below.

WebDriver extension

```
    public static void SwitchToWindow(this IWebDriver @driver,string windowTitle)
    {
        var windows = @driver.WindowHandles.Count;           
        if (windows > 1)
        {
            var windowHandles = @driver.WindowHandles;
            @driver.SwitchTo().Window(
                    windowHandles.First(x =>
                    @driver.SwitchTo().Window(x).Title.Contains(windowTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                    ));
        }
        else @driver.SwitchTo().Window(@driver.WindowHandles.FirstOrDefault());            
    }
```

String Extension, sometimes window titles can be very long, so just identify a part of it.

```
    public static bool Contains(this string @string, string comparedValue, StringComparison compareType)
    {
        return @string?.IndexOf(comparedValue, compareType) >= 0;
    }

    public static bool Contains(this List<string> @string, string comparedValue, StringComparison compareType)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(@string.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(comparedValue, compareType)));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Let me try to implement your suggestion, then i'll get back if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My first code before the focus window method is a s follows:-

```
private void CreateWindowTitle()
{
    windowTitle = "Task";
}

public Task ShouldFocusTaskWindow()
{
    var popup = GetBrowserName();
    FocusWindowOrPopup(windowTitle);
    WaitUntilVisible(By.Id("Content_ctrlTaskControl_lblCaseNumber"));
    return this;
}
```